# Java - Web services over JMS

Tags: java, soap, jms

I'm confused.  I have a situation where I need to accept incoming messages from outside the company and by other technology stacks, fool with them, and send a response back.  I've got both ActiveMQ and WebSphere MQ (we're on a WebSphere application server, and I'm trying to decide if I like one over the other), and I understand how to set up the message listeners.  I think.  What I don't know is what format the incoming message takes.  Is it a web service and can be treated like one?  Or a JMS message?  Or a hybrid of the two?  Like I said, I'm totally confused.  Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is like a soap/http, the body of the text message has the soap message and then, your webservice unmarshall the payload and get java beans.

you will need two queue: request and reply, there is no bidirectional comunication by the same queue

try to develop with jax-ws because is and java standard, some apis like axis are less compatible.

here is an example:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/tutorials/0903_adams/index.html?ca=dat

Comment: Okay.  Do you need the message listeners, then?

Comment: with jax-ws no, you need to put your binding on the wsdl in soap address and the framework will make all.

`<wsdl:port binding="tns:EchoSOAP" name="EchoServicePort">
   <soap:address location="jms:REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL" />
  </wsdl:port>`